# $cancelSubscriptionUrl in a Contribution Receipt email links to http://%22%22/

Tags: wordpress, civicontribute, email, contributions, receipts

A contributor complains it is not possible to remove from the automatic renewal option using a link in  "You can cancel the auto-renewal option by visiting this web page." sentence. I've checked and indeed, the link redirects to **http://%22%22/**

Link token  `{$cancelSubscriptionUrl}`   has been found in **Contributions - Receipt (on-line)** message template.

Underneath link ("You can update billing details for this automatically renewed membership by visiting ...") works fine.

Should this "$cancelSubscriptionUrl" be activates / set up somewhere in CiviCRM admin area? Or the link is being sanitized somehow? Wrong / non-existing token maybe? There is not much about **$cancelSubscriptionUrl** in the civicrm codebase, a few mentions found in email templates only.

WordPress 5.8 and CiviCRM 5.39.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case it was "Enable self-service cancellation of a recurring contribution" checkbox on iATS payment settings page.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Could you check if there are any special chars in the base url defined in civicrm.settings.php?

Comment: Thank you for your response. Nothing odd, apart from double quote around $civicrm_setting['URL Preferences']['userFrameworkResourceURL'] value under "Additional settings generated by installer:"